# how to edit <object> in javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

I am editing a system and I noticed a weird tag `<object>` I tried to search for it but didn't get any luck.
the code looks something like this : 
`<object width="50" height="10" tabIndex="12345" id="test" classid="ghjkl" />`

so what I need to do is I need to edit the value of this textbox but I didn't get any luck with that.
I have tried to grab it by id (and it worked) but I couldn't get the exact value or edit it's value.
any ideas ?

Comment: what do you mean by the `value` of the element?

Comment: @Mamun the element is a textfiled so in normal textfield we can use something like textfield.value = "bla bla bla" , but here it is a different story

Comment: "Use this element to embed multimedia (like audio, video, Java applets, ActiveX, PDF, and Flash) in your web pages." [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp)

Answer (score 2):

> The HTML `<object>` element represents an external resource, which can be treated as an image, a nested browsing context, or a resource to be handled by a plugin.

There is no `value` attribute for `<object>` element. Please check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) link for all the available attributes present in `<object>`.

But there is `data` attribute which you can modify:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
  document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('data', 'new-movie.swf');
  console.log(document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('data'));
}, false);
```

```html
<object width="50" height="10" tabIndex="12345" id="test" classid="ghjkl" data="movie.swf"
  type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></object>
```

Comment: I get the error `object does not support this property or method`

Comment: I have tried to use document.getElementById and I was able to get the object my only problem is that when I tried to use getAttribute('data') it returned the error : `t is null or not an object` where `t` is the variable I used to store the get by id result

Comment: I get this error : `document.getElementById(...) is null or not an object`

Comment: @keloa, update the question with your full code...may be your code is running before the DOM loaded.

Comment: @keloa, please place your JavaScript code `document.getElementById(........` at the bottom of your HTML body.....OR wrap your code with `document.addEventListener......` like I did...

Comment: the problem is that I'm working on a system which has a lot of code , it's impossible to post here

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want to get the value from object tag you can use this code.

HTML

```
<object width="50" height="10" tabIndex="12345" id="test" classid="ghjkl" />
```

JavaScript

```
var t=document.querySelector("#test");
var htmlDocument= t.contentDocument;
```

If you have jQuery in your project and want to remove the object element you can use the remove method.

```
$("#test").remove();
```

Comment: I get this error : `Object does not support this property or method`